# How to create and initialize a CoreData object before navigating to a new view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a SwiftUI app with two views:

- SessionListView

```
struct SessionListView: View {

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Session.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Session.timestamp, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "finishedTimestamp == nil"),
        animation: .default)
    private var openSessions: FetchedResults<Session>

    [...]

    var body: some View {
        if let openSession = openSessions.first {
            NavigationLink(destination: NewSessionView(session: openSession)) {
                Text("Continue Current Session")
            }
        } else {
            NavigationLink(destination: NewSessionView(session: *?*) {
                Text("Create New Session")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

- NewSessionView (more like ActiveSessionView)

```
struct NewSessionView: View {

    @ObservedObject var session: Session;

    var body: Some View {
        [...]
    }

}
```

My desired outcome is that if the FetchRequest returns an item, we pass the existing item from SessionListView to NewSessionView. If the FetchRequest returns no results, we create a new item, and initialize the `timestamp` variable as such:

```swift
private func createNewSession() {
    let newSession = Session(context: viewContext)
    newSession.timestamp = Date()

    do {
        try viewContext.save()
        isNewSessionCreated = true
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error when creating a new session \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I've tried adding:

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewSessionView(session: newSession)) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

at the of `createNewSession` and calling the method on button click rather than using a NavigationLink in the View itself but that resulted in the session being created and the button text changing to "Continue Current Session". So it did technically work, but it required the user to perform one extra action of clicking the "Continue Current Session" which is terrible design.

I've tried using the `isActive` binding as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:isactive:label:)?changes=latest_beta), but that appears to be deprecated and brought challenges of its own.

I would like to keep the actual creation and initialization of the Session object in the SessionListView and not the NewSessionView if possible.

Does anyone have any pointers I can follow to achieve this? I can post more examples of what I've tried if it helps as well. Thanks!

Comment: you could try to do the `createNewSession()` in `.onAppear { if ...}`, and
 just have one `NavigationLink(...)`.

Comment: Your code implies there will not be more than one session stored, is that correct?

Comment: Usually people switch to a `Button` that sets an item (that is a struct containing the new object and its child context) and use it with `.sheet(item:)` but you could try the `onAppear` way suggested by @workingdogsupportUkraine. You will need to check `onAppear` isn't called twice and you probably also need some logic in `onDisappear` which could get rather messy.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(item:destination:)

Comment: > Your code implies there will not be more than one session stored, is that correct? 
- 
Yes. It was hard for me to distinguish how to exactly store what I want, but the general idea is that there are a bunch of past "Session" objects and there should only ever be 0 or 1 "Open/Active Session" indicated by a lack of a `session.finishedTimestamp` value.

Comment: @malhal could you please explain what you mean using `.sheet(item:)`?